# Binomial distribution births

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve this problem using binomial distribution.

What is the probability that in a group of $100$ people, $10$ of them were born in either March and April.

Binomial distribution formula is : $ 
    \binom{n}{x}p^{x}q^{n-x}$ , where $p$ is probability of success and $q$ the probability of failure.

Probability of failure is:
Probability that no one shares a
birthday

Probability of success is:
$p=1-q$

I tried many approaches but it gave me a negative result which is completely wrong.

I saw many examples on the internet and I found this formula for larger groups :

$P(\text{no one shares a birthday}) = 365 \cdot 364 \cdot 363 \dotsm (365 - N + 1) / 365^{N}$

But I am using months instead of days, so do I need to use $12$ instead of $365$? 
I am not sure how to start.

Comment: The event in question is "person X is born in either March or April".  The probability of that event is $p\sim \frac 2{12}$.  You can use actual day counts to get a tighter grip on $p$, though I still recommend ignoring leap years.  From there, as you suggest, this is a problem for the binomial distribution (or normal approximation thereof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the formula for probability of not sharing a birthday; that's not really applicable here. You're on the right track with the binomial distribution to compute $P(x = 10)$. The probability $p$ that a single person's birthday is in March or April depends on how precise you want to be; a first approximation would be $2/12 = 1/6$, a better approximation would be $\frac{31 + 30}{365} = \frac{61}{365}$. The probability $q$ of *not* being born in March or April is just $1 - p$. We have $n = 100$ and $x = 10$; use the probability mass function that you stated.

Comment: So if I use the Binomial distribution I will get : 100C10 . (61/365)^10 . (304/365)^90 , is it enough to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, computing that will give the answer. Note that this is $P(x = 10)$, not $P(x \geq 10)$.

Comment: I  can only  use Binomial distribution in this case because it says 10 people out of 100 (exactly 10) right?

Comment: No, the binomial distribution is appropriate in general for this, because we have a discrete number of identical events that can have one of two outcomes. If we wanted to find $P(x \geq 10)$ (or any other probability involving an inequality), we'd have to use the cumulative distribution function instead of the probability mass function.

Comment: I understood, thank you for your help